# Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this error
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: could you please give detail when are you receiving this error? are you trying to login for fetching in-app content?

Comment: I am using payment method in my app, when I click "buy now" option I am getting this error

Comment: There could be few reasons like no in-app product created in iTunes, Financial /Tax agreement is not completed on iTunes.

Comment: I checked, everything are perfect.  I am using SKPaymentTransaction method. My transaction is getting failed always and shows above error